# Clojure Koan section 8, #5

Tags: clojure, lisp

Why is this valid:

```
(= '(:anything :goes :here) (filter (fn [x] true) '(:anything :goes :here)))
```

but not this?

```
(= (:anything :goes :here) (filter (fn [x] true) '(:anything :goes :here)))
```

or

```
(= (:anything :goes :here) (filter (fn [x] true) (:anything :goes :here)))
```

or even

```
(= '(:anything :goes :here) (filter (fn [x] true) (:anything :goes :here)))
```

Is there a particular reason that the second arg to filter is a quoted list rather than a plain list?

```
user=> (filter (fn [x] true) (:abc :def :ghi))
IllegalArgumentException Don't know how to create ISeq from: clojure.lang.Keyword  clojure.lang.RT.seqFrom (RT.java:505)
```

As a matter of fact, I still am unsure when exactly a list is also a function call. It's related to quoting it seems. Are all "plain lists" required to be quoted unless they are empty lists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a list is evaluated, the first element is assumed to be a function (or macro or special form).

When the first element of the list is a function, all the arguments are first evaluated, and then the function is applied to the resulting values.

If the first element of the list is a macro or special form, each of the arguments may or may not be evaluated depending on the macro/special form.

Clojure will evaluate a list whose first element is a keyword by trying to find that keyword as key in the map given as argument to the keyword function, and then return the corresponding value, otherwise return the next argument (if given).  Thus `(:anything :goes: :here)` will return `here`.

`'` is a read macro that puts it's argument into a `quote` special form. *I.e.* `'anything` =>`(quote anything)`

In your case:

When `=` is evaluated, the values of `(:anything :goes: here)` and/or `'(:anything goes here)` have to be evaluated. Evaluation of the first one will result in `:here`.  (In other lisps it would result in an error). `'(:anything :goes :here)`, however is a short form of `(quote (:anything :goes :here))`, and `quote` is a special form that returns it's arguments *unevaluated*, resulting in the list `(:anything :goes: here)` which is then passed to `=` or `filter` without further evaluation.

What's happening in each of the cases is then:

```
(= '(:anything :goes :here) (filter (fn [x] true) '(:anything :goes :here)))
```

`=`is comparing `(:anything :goes :here)`to `(:anything :goes :here)`, resulting in true

```
(= (:anything :goes :here) (filter (fn [x] true) '(:anything :goes :here)))
```

`:here` is compared to `(:anything :goes :here)`, resulting in false

```
(= (:anything :goes :here) (filter (fn [x] true) (:anything :goes :here)))
(= '(:anything :goes :here) (filter (fn [x] true) (:anything :goes :here)))
```

In both of these, `filter` is applied to the single keyword `:here`, resulting in an error.

Comment: I guess it's worth saying that this is true for pretty much every Lisp, not just clojure

Comment: You're slightly wrong. `:anything` is a keyword, and it it pretty well defined as a function. See https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Keyword.java, `invoke(Object, Object)` method. In short, it asks its first argument to look up itself, if the first argument can, and if it can't, it defaults to standard `get` function. In both cases second argument acts as default value. So the following expression: `(:abcd :defg :hijk)` will return `:hijk`, as default value.

Comment: @VladimirMatveev  Thanks for the correction. I have now updated the answer.

Comment: @jozefg The handling of keywords as functions (not originally mentioned) is not common in other lisps.

Comment: @TerjeD. I was refering to the first part on quoting

Comment: The elaborate explanation is very much appreciated. +5 if I could.

Comment: @jozefg  I know, but as the answer was edited to put more emphasis on clojure-specific things, I wanted to indicate (to others) that your initially correct comment had become somewhat outdated.

Comment: @TerjeD. Oh sorry about that, I missed the edits. In any case +1